# Tensorflow Keras, raise ValueError( ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am attempting to create a custom loss function for a Chess ANN using Python and the Keras library, the goal of which is to heavily dissuade making illegal moves, by checking the validity of the move in the custom loss function.

```
def source_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    
int_to_piece = {
    0:'_',
    1:'p', 2:'r', 3:'n', 4:'b', 5:'q', 6:'k',
    7:'P', 8:'R', 9:'N', 10:'B', 11:'Q', 12:'K'
}

#  Converts board locations represented by integer to indexes
int_to_coordinates = {
0:[0, 0],   1:[0, 1],  2:[0, 2],  3:[0, 3],  4:[0, 4],  5:[0, 5],  6:[0, 6],  7:[0, 7],
8:[1, 0],   9:[1, 1], 10:[1, 2], 11:[1, 3], 12:[1, 4], 13:[1, 5], 14:[1, 6], 15:[1, 7],
16:[2, 0], 17:[2, 1], 18:[2, 2], 19:[2, 3], 20:[2, 4], 21:[2, 5], 22:[2, 6], 23:[2, 7],
24:[3, 0], 25:[3, 1], 26:[3, 2], 27:[3, 3], 28:[3, 4], 29:[3, 5], 30:[3, 6], 31:[3, 7],
32:[4, 0], 33:[4, 1], 34:[4, 2], 35:[4, 3], 36:[4, 4], 37:[4, 5], 38:[4, 6], 39:[4, 7],
40:[5, 0], 41:[5, 1], 42:[5, 2], 43:[5, 3], 44:[5, 4], 45:[5, 5], 46:[5, 6], 47:[5, 7],
48:[6, 0], 49:[6, 1], 50:[6, 2], 51:[6, 3], 52:[6, 4], 53:[6, 5], 54:[6, 6], 55:[6, 7],
56:[7, 0], 57:[7, 1], 58:[7, 2], 59:[7, 3], 60:[7, 4], 61:[7, 5], 62:[7, 6], 63:[7, 7],
}


tensorDataTrue = y_true.numpy()
tensorDataPred = y_pred.numpy()

loss_Array = []



for i in range(len(tensorDataTrue)):
    
    
    sourceTileTrue = tensorDataTrue[i][0][0]
    targetTileTrue = tensorDataTrue[i][1][0]
    sourceTilePred = np.argmax(tensorDataPred[i])

    

    gameBoard = tensorDataTrue[i][2]


    pieceType = int_to_piece[gameBoard[sourceTileTrue]]
    
    

    # Retrieve the coordinates
    coordSourceTrue = int_to_coordinates[sourceTileTrue]
    coordTargetTrue = int_to_coordinates[targetTileTrue]
    coordSourcePred = int_to_coordinates[sourceTilePred]
    
    
    validMove = False

    # Calculates the loss
    lossValue = abs(sourceTileTrue-sourceTilePred)

    if(pieceType=="p" ):
        validMove = IsValidMoveBlackPawn(coordSourcePred,coordTargetTrue)
    elif(pieceType=="P"):
        validMove = IsValidMoveWhitePawn(coordSourcePred,coordTargetTrue)
    elif(pieceType=="b"):
        validMove = IsValidMoveBishop(coordSourcePred,coordTargetTrue)
    elif(pieceType=="B"):
        validMove = IsValidMoveBishop(coordSourcePred,coordTargetTrue)
    elif(pieceType=="r"):
        validMove = IsValidMoveRook(coordSourcePred,coordTargetTrue)
    elif(pieceType=="R"):
        validMove = IsValidMoveRook(coordSourcePred,coordTargetTrue)
    elif(pieceType=="q"):
        validMove = IsValidMoveQueen(coordSourcePred,coordTargetTrue)
    elif(pieceType=="Q"):
        validMove = IsValidMoveQueen(coordSourcePred,coordTargetTrue)
    elif(pieceType=="k"):
        validMove = IsValidMoveKing(coordSourcePred,coordTargetTrue)
    elif(pieceType=="K"):
        validMove = IsValidMoveKing(coordSourcePred,coordTargetTrue)
    elif(pieceType=="n"):
        validMove = IsValidMoveKnight(coordSourcePred,coordTargetTrue)
    elif(pieceType=="N"):
        validMove = IsValidMoveKnight(coordSourcePred,coordTargetTrue)

    if(validMove == False):
        lossValue+=100

    loss_Array.append(lossValue)
    lossValue = 0
    

# Return the final loss value
return loss_Array
```

But I am getting this error: ValueError: No gradients provided for any `variable: (['dense_8/kernel:0', 'dense_8/bias:0', 'dense_9/kernel:0', 'dense_9/bias:0', 'dense_10/kernel:0', 'dense_10/bias:0', 'dense_11/kernel:0', 'dense_11/bias:0', 'dense_12/kernel:0', 'dense_12/bias:0', 'dense_13/kernel:0', 'dense_13/bias:0', 'dense_14/kernel:0', 'dense_14/bias:0', 'dense_15/kernel:0', 'dense_15/bias:0', 'source_head/kernel:0', 'source_head/bias:0', 'target_head/kernel:0', 'target_head/bias:0'],)`

Could I ask what the loss function should be returning and how the calculated loss will be used to train the ANN? And is there another way of dissuading illegal moves?

I am currently returning an array of integers representing the calculated loss for each of the training data samples in the batch.

I am expecting the ANN to compile, train on the training data I am giving it.

This is the command I am using to train the ANN:

```
ANNCA_White.fit(finWhiteBoards, [finWhiteSourceMoves, finWhiteTargetMoves], batch_size=1, epochs=1000, shuffle=True, verbose=1)
```

Comment: Losses have to be differentiable, yours is not, this will never work, you probably want to use RL (where the reward function does not have to be differentiable).

Comment: I understand, thank you very much! I will look into using reinforcing learning then.